# YouTube api Error

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am a little confuse! I am trying to develop a script that can pull youtube video id in python. So I went ahead and set up my youtube API key.I use this page to generate the URL.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

This page generated a sample JSON table with the video ID. But when I put this url in my browser

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=gullybop&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

and yes I filled in my api. I expected to get back a JSON table with the vid ids but I get this instead

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
  {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
  }
 ],
 "code": 400,
 "message": "Bad Request"
 }
 }
```

I don't think my API key is invalid

I expected when I put the URL in the browser it would return a JSON table with vid ids but instead I got that error above. 
Why am I getting this error ?
Thank you Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got JSON results when I accessed this URL with my API Key. So your API key will be invalid nothing else. Try to create another project in API console and create a key without any referrer no server IP. Only generate 1 key in a project. Dont forget to enable YouTube Data API v3 in API manager.